# Android animations between activities transition

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

How to impliment following animation between activity transition in android

http://share.framerjs.com/lg0nu9ecekfy/

Comment: Are you sure they are activity transitions? You can also define also those UI components in a single activity and only setVisibility to those that are supposed to be visible at the right moment...

Comment: Thanks for your response @pepan can you explain how can I achieve this animation currently I have only UI setup as it next step is to achieve this animation

Comment: Your link expired